# how to get dates in R

Tags: python, r

`dataflair_rng['date'] = pd.date_range('2021-12-01 12:00:00', periods = 50, freq ='H')`

this syntax will give me next 50 points from `2021-12-01 12:00:00`

can we do that in R ??

if yes then How ? (I used `plyr` but it just resample the data )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library("chron")
date_dataflair <- seq.dates("01/12/2021", by = "day", length = 50)
```

For Date time

```
seq(from = as.POSIXct("2021-12-01", tz = "GMT"), 
length.out = 50, 
by = "days")
```

Comment: Thanks , i saw this , but what about hour frequency

Comment: If this is your desired answer please vote

Comment: ill do vote , but concern is , hourly means day single (24 hours on that day) , Like -: `"24-01-21 06:00:00"` `"24-01-21 07:00:00"` and more

Comment: is there any way to remove `GMT` ??? if i don't write anything there it will come up with `IST`  .. i don't want anything there .. how to do that??